# Sphinx: Use already translated files without creating translatable files

Tags: internationalization, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I am trying to figure a way to use already translated .md files (Russian Language) with Sphinx. I use [readthedocs.io](https://readthedocs.io) and I have already read the process of making translatable files (`.po`/`.pot`) from:

(1) https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/localization.html
(2) https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/manage-translations.html.

This process requires to make `.po` or `.pot` files, translate them, and then produce translated html files - served under https://project.readthedocs.io/$language/$version

What I want is to use a different directory (for example named `ru`) and place there the Russian `.md` files.

Is that possible? How is it possible to avoid creating these `.po`/`.pot` files?

Comment: I am now in the same position. What solution did you use in the end?

Comment: IMHO, this is not a question about Sphinx, but readthedocs.